# UITextView allignment changing when updated

Tags: swift, uitextview

Im trying to keep my text aligned to the center when updating the UITextView but for some reason all of the other settings save except the center align.

Here is where I initialize my text view

```
  private let displayTextView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Str", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(36, weight: .semibold)])
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\nStr", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(18, weight: .medium), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]))
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.isSelectable = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textView
  }()
```

Here is where I update my text view

```
  private func getDisplayText(pageNumber: Int) -> NSAttributedString {
    switch tapCount {
    case 0:
      let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Create", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(36, weight: .semibold)])
      attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\nStr", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(18, weight: .medium), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]))
      return attributedText
    case 1:
      let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Str", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(36, weight: .semibold)])
      attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\nStr", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(18, weight: .medium), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]))
      return attributedText
    case 2:
      let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Str", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(36, weight: .semibold)])
      attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\nStr", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(18, weight: .medium), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]))
      return attributedText
    default:
      let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Str", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(36, weight: .semibold)])
      attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\nStr", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.fableFont(18, weight: .medium), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]))
      return attributedText
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can create one `NSMutableAttributedString` change text only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append paragraphStyle to Attributed String

```
 private func getDisplayText(pageNumber: Int) -> NSAttributedString {

    // Define paragraph style - you got to pass it along to NSAttributedString constructor
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

    var stringVal = ""

  switch pageNumber {

  case 0:
   stringVal = "Create"

  default:
   stringVal = "Str"

  }

   let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringVal, attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36, weight: .semibold)])
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\nStr", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .medium), .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]))
    return attributedText
}
```

Comment: I had to do let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleStringValue, attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36, weight: .semibold), .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]) in order to get the title to work aswell. Thanks